# Querying ActivityName in _JourneyActivity data view returns no results

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, sql, data-views

My brain is breaking.

I have journeys deploying emails in my Salesforce Marketing Cloud instance. According to all of Salesforce's documentation (specifically [**this**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_journey_activity.htm&type=5) page), I should be able to query the `_JourneyActivity` data view.

My query is as simple as this:

```
select ActivityName from _JourneyActivity
```

But I get no results. There's no error saying that the column or field doesn't exist. It's just blank. How can that possibly be when I have Journeys and Activities related to those journeys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should build your Data Extension as it is noted in the documentation link you've linked. 
This means all the fields with their correct attribute types and length.

Once you do - your SQL Query would ask you to include the 3 non-nullable fields in the query - `VersionID`, `ActivityID` and `ActivityExternalKey`.

Once you fix your Data Extension and include these 3 fields in your SQL query - it will run fine.

Comment: Thing is, I did that. The data extension had all the fields in the query. But the simplest form of my query just selects "ActivityName" and even that didn't return any results.

Comment: Odd. It works fine on my end. Double check that you have all the field types and nullable-properties (where applicable) set correctly. Are you trying to query from the same BU as the Journey? Also noting Data Views only have data up to past 6 months.

Comment: I ended up finding the same data in other tables, but I think the issue was that the field lengths were too short. I'm working in another client's account, and I had the same issue when trying to join the _bounce table to the _subscribers table, and it turned out that I had to preface the _subscribers table with ent., even though I didn't have to do that for the _bounce table. Maybe bounces are stored at the BU level and subscribers are stored at a higher level?